# How can I refactor this code to use a single method?

Tags: go

I've got those 2 duplicated methods `coolFunc()`:

```
import (
    foo "github.com/..." # imports API foo
    bar "github.com/..." # imports API bar

type Client struct {
    fooClient            *foo.APIClient
    barClient            *bar.APIClient
    car                  string
    dar                  string
}

func (c *Client) coolFunc(fooClient *foo.APIClient) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(context.Background(), foo.StructA, foo.StructB{
            Car: c.car,
            Dar: c.dar,
    })
}

func (c *Client) coolFunc(barClient *bar.APIClient) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(context.Background(), bar.StructA, bar.StructB{
            Car: c.car,
            Dar: c.dar,
    })
}
```

is there a way to refactor it into a single method? My concern is what if I've got 5 clients:

```
type Client struct {
    fooClient            *foo.APIClient
    barClient            *bar.APIClient
    // #3, #4, #5 *Client etc
    car                  string
    dar                  string
}
```

and the `fooClient / barClient` is not really being used in those methods anyway.

The issue is even though `foo.StructA` is defined the same as `bar.StructA` apparently there're some runtime issues when I trying to use the same struct from a different package (e.g., using `bar.StructA` in `coolFunc()`. I haven't got the access to change APIs either.

Comment: I feel like I don't understand what kind of problem do you want to solve with provided code? Could you write down what `coolFunc` is supposed to do? Current code will not compile since it is not allowed to have two methods with the same name for the same receiver. Structures defined in different packages are different structures, even if the signature looks the same.

Comment: `coolFunc` returns a context with a key-value pair and its key/value is taken should reference the values from different packages (foo/bar).

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you want a Generic type, which is not available yet, but :

On this function, since is a method from Client {}, you have access to the  parameters, what you can do is something like this

```
type enumApiStruct int 

const (
    apiBar = iota +1
    apiFoo
)

func (c *Client) coolFunc(ApiTobeUsed int ) context.Context {
   switch ApiTobeUsed {
   case 1: 
      return context.WithValue(context.Background(), bar.StructA,bar.StructB{
            Car: c.car,
            Dar: c.dar,
      })
   case 2:
       // and keep going until all api clients are done
   }
}
```

Or you can use a interface {} On the parameter, but them you have to assert the interface{} to the struct, so if else in any case
https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

```
func (c *Client) coolFunc(ApiTobeUsed interface{}) context.Context {
   // 
}
```

Other solution, since you have access to the list of structs, you can compare and check by the one that is not nil, to be used.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be use of an empty interface and a type switch

```
func (c *Client) coolFunc(i interface{}) (*context.Context, error) {
    switch v := i.(type) { // can drop the  v := if not using anything from the APIClient
    case *foo.APIClient:
        return &context.WithValue(context.Background(), bar.StructA,bar.StructB{
            Car: c.car,
            Dar: c.dar,
      }), nil
    case *bar.APIClient:
        return &context.WithValue(context.Background(), bar.StructA,bar.StructB{
            Car: c.car,
            Dar: c.dar,
      }), nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unsupported APIClient")
}
```